# Error Code: 520003 when test implicit payment in live paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Error Code: 520003 when test implicit payment for send money to other paypal account in live paypal ?

My paypal app Status:Approved Conditionally

When i test it's show error like this.

....................................................................................................................................................................

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for AdaptiveCall(), called in /home1/mkjhjjjj/public_html/note.php on line 91 and defined in /home1/mkjhjjjj/public_html/note.php on line 3
ERROR Code: 520003 
ERROR Message: Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
```

this is my code.

....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<?php

function AdaptiveCall($bodyparams, $method, $payKey) {

try
{

    $body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));
    $url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/".$method."");
    $params = array("http" => array( 
                        "method" => "POST",
                        "content" => $body_data,
                            "header" => "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: payments_api1.mysite.com\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV\r\n" .
                                        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV\r\n" 
                                    )
                    );


    //create stream context
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);


    //open the stream and send request
     $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

    //get response
     $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

    //check to see if stream is open
     if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

    //close the stream
     fclose($fp);

    //parse the ap key from the response

    $keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
            $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

 //print the response to screen for testing purposes
    If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") {
        echo "<strong>".$method ."</strong><br>";
         foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
        echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";

    }
    // Return payKey
    global $payKey;
    if(!empty($kArray['payKey'])) { $payKey = $kArray['payKey']; return($payKey); }

     }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR Code: ' .  $kArray["error(0).errorId"] . " <br/>";
      echo 'ERROR Message: ' .  urldecode($kArray["error(0).message"]) . " <br/>";
    }

   }


catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
  }
}



//Create Pay body
$bodyparams = array (   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                        'actionType' => 'PAY',
                        'currencyCode' => 'USD',
                        'receiverList.receiver(0).email' => 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com',
                        'receiverList.receiver(0).amount' => '1.00',
                        'senderEmail' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                        'memo' => 'Test memo',
                        'ipnNotificationUrl' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php',
                        'cancelUrl' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php',
                        'returnUrl' => 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php'
                    );

                    // Call Pay API
AdaptiveCall($bodyparams, "Pay");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Live environment, **make sure to update the endpoint**, from your code I can see you are pointing to Sandbox "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/" and that's probably why you are getting incorrect credentials error.

Make sure you are using the correct endpoint with correct API credentials for that particular environment. For more information, please visit the
**Going Live Checklist** page > [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/)

If you haven't done it already, in order to get "**Implicit Payments**" permissions for a Live account, you will need to request your APP id (Classic) at https://developer.paypal.com > Applications > My apps > Create and manage Classic API apps. 
Make sure to select "**Implicit Send Money**" from the Basic Payments options.